# zoom control overlaps custom control in google map area

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

i am having 1 div control and added it to the google map on LEFT_BOTTOM position. and zoomControl is true.
when my div moves to zoom control. zoom control is overlapping my div. how can i avoid it.

i am unable to upload snap. that will describe the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution by setting z-index of my custom control

mycontrol.style.z-index = 5;

it works.